# Am I using the subjunctive correctly?

Tags: subjunctives

Can you please tell me if I've used the subjunctive correctly in this sentence?

Sara and Seema's insistence that the book feature as its cover a controversial photograph caused a lot of disagreement among publishing executives.

Comment: The sentence is not incorrect, but "feature a controversial photograph as its cover" could be better than "feature as its cover a controversial photograph". We rarely separate a verb from its direct object, unless perhaps the adverb phrase in between is fairly short and the object noun phrase is fairly long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the verb "feature" is correctly in the subjunctive mood.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's correct.  There is also nothing wrong with how you've worded it.  Aschepler answered it differently as he didn't like where you place "as its cover"; however, I have no problem with it in your answer.  Yours may sound a little poetic, but I don't even think that.  I wouldn't flinch if someone said that to me.